# solution for jump game problem is not running properly

Tags: java, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

You are given an integer array nums. You are initially positioned at the array's first index, and each element in the array represents your maximum jump length at that position.

Return true if you can reach the last index, or false otherwise.

my code is running for some test cases but When I submit it gets failed, need help.

```
class Solution {
    public boolean canJump(int[] nums) {
        return helper(nums, 0);
    }
    public boolean helper(int[] nums, int currentPointer){
        if(currentPointer == nums.length - 1) {
            return true;
        }
        boolean ans = false;
        for(int i = 1; i <= nums[currentPointer]; i++) {
            ans = helper(nums, currentPointer + i);
        }   

        if(ans) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you,  please, include a link to the problem source?

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game/

Comment: `nums = {1000, 1}` will the code do something silly? I think it will try to access past the end of the array.

Comment: The tag [recursive-datastructures] seems wrong for this question. The tag [recursion] seems a better choice.

Comment: Do you know why some of your test cases failed? What error message(s) did you get?

Comment: no error message were shown there

Comment: Any jump that can go past the end of the array should return `true`, because each element in the array is the maximum jump from that position. Consider something like `if ( position + nums [position] >= nums.length - 1) { return true; }`.